# How is the YOLOv8 best loss model selected by the trainer class?

Tags: python, yolo, loss

From the YOLOv8 documentation, it is not clear to me which loss metric the YOLOv8 trainer class uses in determining the best loss model that is saved in a training run. Is it based on the validation or training loss?

Specifically, when I look at the outputs from a YOLOv8 training run, I do not see any metadata indicating which epoch resulted in the best loss model saved at runs/train/weights/best.pt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [save_model](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/f6e393c1d25a198d3da9ae9b9e37209a88cb93dc/ultralytics/yolo/engine/trainer.py#L383) function you can see that it uses the maximum `fitness` to save the best model. The [fitness](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/f2a7a29e531ad029255c8ec180ff65de24f42e8d/ultralytics/yolo/utils/metrics.py#L495) is defined as the weighted combination of 4 metrics `[P, R, mAP@0.5, mAP@0.5:0.95]`. `P` and `R` are disregarded for some reason. `mAP@0.5`, `mAP@0.5:0.95` are weighted 0.1 and 0.9 respectively.

If `fitness` cannot be found, [loss](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/f6e393c1d25a198d3da9ae9b9e37209a88cb93dc/ultralytics/yolo/engine/trainer.py#L446) is used instead

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! Based on looking at the code a little bit more, am I reading correctly that fitness is always calculated from validation images?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.